# Flutter Hive: values are not deleted

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-hive

I am testing Hive NoSQL Database.
I have succeeded in creating a database, putting a value, and getting a value.

1. However, I failed to delete the value.
   I've done a lot of searching, but I can't figure it out.
2. Also, when saving the value of TextFormField using Button, Get.Back(); was used using GetX, but it did not work.
   The value is saved, but the screen is not popped.
   So, I popped it using Navigation and it worked.
   I don't know what was the cause.

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me what the problem is.

**home_screen.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hive_test1/component/todo_card.dart';
import 'package:hive_test1/db/database.dart';
import 'package:hive_test1/scr/form_screen.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Get.to(() => FormScreen());
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('Hive Test'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: ValueListenableBuilder(
            valueListenable: Hive.box<Todos>('testTable').listenable(),
            builder: (context, Box<Todos> box, child) {
              return ListView.separated(
                itemCount: box.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                  var item = box.get(index);

                  if (item == null) {
                    return Center(
                        child: Container(
                      child: Text('null'),
                    ));
                  } else {
                    return TodoCard(
                        title: item.title,
                        note: item.note,
                        dateTime: item.dateTime,
                        id: item.id,
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            box.deleteAt(item.id);  // This is not working.
                          });
                        });
                  }
                },
                separatorBuilder: (_, index) {
                  return const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                    child: Divider(),
                  );
                },
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**form_screen.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_test1/db/database.dart';

class FormScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FormScreenState createState() => _FormScreenState();
}

class _FormScreenState extends State<FormScreen> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey();

  String? title;
  String? note;
  DateTime? dateTime;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('Form Screen'),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              renderTextFormField(
                  label: 'Title',
                  hintText: 'Please enter a title',
                  onSaved: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      title = val;
                    });
                  },
                  validator: (val) {
                    if (val.length < 1) {
                      return 'Please enter a title';
                    }
                    return null;
                  }),
              renderTextFormField(
                  label: 'Note',
                  hintText: 'Please enter a value',
                  onSaved: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      note = val;
                    });
                  },
                  validator: (val) {
                    if (val.length < 1) {
                      return 'Please enter a note';
                    }
                    return null;
                  }),
              saveButton(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  renderTextFormField({
    required String label,
    required onSaved,
    required validator,
    required hintText,
  }) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              label,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
          onSaved: onSaved,
          validator: validator,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),                  
            hintText: hintText,           
            border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  saveButton() {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              var box = Hive.box<Todos>('testTable');
              if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {               
                formKey.currentState?.save();              
                int id = 0; 
                if (box.isNotEmpty) {
                  final prevItem = box.getAt(box.length - 1);
                  id = prevItem!.id + 1;
                }
                box.put(
                  id,
                  Todos(
                    title: title!,
                    note: note!,
                    id: id,
                    dateTime: dateTime = DateTime.now(),
                  ),
                );
                Get.snackbar(
                  'Saved!',
                  'Your form has been saved!',
                );
                print(title);

                Navigator.of(context).pop();  // this is working
                // Get.Back();  <- Not Working

              } else if (formKey.currentState?.validate() == null) {
                Get.snackbar(
                  "Required",
                  "All fields are required!",
                  snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.warning_amber_rounded,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
            child: const Text(
              'Save',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**database.dart**

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'database.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Todos {

  Todos(
      {required this.title,
      required this.note,
      required this.id,
      required this.dateTime});

  @HiveField(0) 
  int id;

  @HiveField(1)
  String title;

  @HiveField(2)
  String note;

  @HiveField(3)
  DateTime dateTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was no answer to my #1 question, so I tried to find the answer myself.
I haven't found an answer for the 2nd one yet.

Answer 1 should have declared VoidCallback instead of Function when declaring a Function.

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TodoCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String note;
  final int id;
  final DateTime dateTime;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;  
// This is answer. VoidCallback instead of Function

renderIconButton() {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: widget.onPressed,  // This is answer.
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.delete,
        color: Colors.red,
        size: 25,
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
                  return TodoCard(
                      title: item.title,
                      note: item.note,
                      dateTime: item.dateTime,
                      id: item.id,
                      onPressed: () => box.deleteAt(index),
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not deleting with `index` I guess. If that so, to delete with `id` use `.delete` instead of `.deleteAt` method like:

   ```
   onPressed: () async {
                  setState(() {
                        await box.delete(item.id);
                      });
                    }
   ```
2. `SnackBar`s and `dialog`s are considered as `route`s in GetX. Therefore, you need to close that route using `Get.back()` if they are open in order to navigate away from the containing screen/page:

   Get.back();  // to close the opened snackbar or dialog
   Get.back();  // to close the current page and go back

You need to use `Get.back()` twice essentially. But there's a problem with this. Calling `Get.back()` twice immediately closes your snackbar and never shown. You could use `Future.delayed` to overcome this:

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), ()=> Get.back()); // allows the snackbar to be displayed for 3 seconds before closing

Get.back(); // Go back
```